Would a current pass in a resistless wire, like a superconducting one, when its ends are connected to the terminals of an ideal battery?
Would a current pass in a superconducting wire, when its ends are connected to the terminals of an ideal battery? If the answer is yes, wouldn't that violate KVL because the voltage rise in the source isn't balanced by a voltage drop anywhere in the loop?

Have a look here. They discuss details.

@periblepsis that link has a horribly clumsy presentation, not wrong in what it says, but could say more, could be a lot better, and doesn't discuss the next problem of how to change an existing field. I wonder if there's a better one out there somewhere, I'll keep my eyes open.

Won't the current linearly rise (due to self inductance) over a few nano/micro seconds and then, the superconductor will become a normal conductor due to the generated magnetism. I'm no expert of course. It will have inductance if it has a finite size i.e. it isn't infinitely small.

@Andyaka This seems to be a hypothetical question with ideal superconductor with no inductance and ability to carry infinite current without turning into regular conductor (and collapsing the universe with infinitely high magnetic field strength, a nice side effect).

@Justme I look forward to that side effect LOL

There ain't such a thing as an ideal short circuit and an ideal battery.
When you build a single wire out of superconducting material and think of it as an ideal resistor with zero impedance, it isn't. It may have zero resistance, but it certainly doesn't have zero impedance. It still acts as an inductance. Yes, even a single wire not coiled around an inductor core acts as an inductance.
So, the ideal battery (if there was such a thing) would give the voltage U.
The superconducting inductor with zero resistance gives the current rise, dI/dt.
$$ U = L \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} $$
So, there you have it: the current starts to gradually rise, and the rise rate is determined by the inductance and the voltage. Since there's no resistance and the energy in the battery is infinite, the current just rises and rises with no bounds.
Eventually though, the current would be so large that the magnetic field it creates would cause the superconducting wire to no longer be superconducting.
However, if it's an ideal superconductor, something that works despite the magnetic field, the system would store more and more energy in the magnetic field around the wire.
Also the magnetic field would start traveling through the entire space as an electromagnetic wave, at the speed of light. It becomes stronger and stronger. Eventually in the nearby galaxies, the magnetic field would be massive and would cause objects made out of magnetic materials to be strongly attracted to our galaxy, even overcoming the gravitational effects of the galaxies.

Let's just assume for the sake of the argument that there such a thing a zero inductance wire. I think assuming that won't harm any known physics. That being said, how things would work?

@Jack My answer says that case already. Such a scenario cannot exist with equations you want.

@Jack It couldn't work with no inductance.  The voltage across an ideal battery is always constant, regardless of the load.  The voltage across the ends of a perfect superconductor is alwats zero, regardless of the current.  Connecting the two together can't produce results that make any sense.

@Jack, for the "no inductance" case, see my answer here to a previous question.

However you are wrong to say it doesn't "harm physics" to assume no inductance. Currents always produce magnetic fields and therefore all conductors have inductance. In circuit theory we assume those inductances are negligible for interconnect wires, but that approximation is simply not valid for your problem.

Yes, current will flow in a superconductor if connected to battery.
It does not violate KCL or KVL or any other formulas, because the voltage drop happens in the non-superconducting parts, like in the internal resistance of a battery.
Edit: This answer was made before the battery and the whole circuit was suddenly defined as ideal and without inductance. So the KVL does not apply as the circuit would contradict with itself if there is an ideal non-zero supply and ideal short circuit as the load.

I am assuming Ideality everywhere in this scenario. That being said, I'm assuming the DC power supply is ideal with no internal resistance!

But there will still have the battery internal resistor

@Jack This limitation was not in the original question. You are then left with formulas that contradict. The current would be infinite but you can't have contradicting voltages that are both zero and non-zero at the same time. Do you also assume no inductance in the superconductor? Is speed of light or electricity infinite or finite?

So what does this tell me? Does it tell that in such scenario KVL isn't valid to apply? Yes I am assuming no inductance and the speed of electricity is finite equals to the speed of light like it should be.

@Jack Exactly, in case of pure DC analysis of an ideal circuit, you cannot have an ideal supply that defines that oltage at load must be non-zero and a load that defines that the voltage at load is zero. Especially if you also define no inductance.
